# SQL server - Alternative to using Aggregates in where Clause

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I have a scenario where I need to get the list of subjects And total number of students failed in those subjects.. Then I need to get the result set from the above where more than 20 students failed I.e subjects list where more than 20 students failed...

```
Select SubjectId, Count(SubjectId) as StudentsFailed 
from tblResults 
group by SubjectId
Having TotalMarks < 35 and Count(SubjectId) > 20
```

The aggregate doesn’t work in where clause, how can I fetch the subjects where more than 20 students failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of failure for the column `TotalMarks` must be moved to a `WHERE` clause:

```
Select SubjectId, Count(SubjectId) as StudentsFailed 
from tblResults 
where TotalMarks < 35
group by SubjectId
Having Count(SubjectId) > 20
```

Also if there is column like `StudentId` then use it inside `Count()`:
`Count(StudentId)` or simply `Count(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not in Having, but just add this condition.

```
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

>

```
Select SubjectId, Count(SubjectId) as StudentsFailed  
from tblResults 
where TotalMarks between 20 
AND 25 group by SubjectId
--Having TotalMarks < 35 and Count(SubjectId) > 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming TotalMarks is a field from tblResults, you should split condition on TotalMarks and Count(SubjectId).

```
select SubjectId, Count(SubjectId) as StudentsFailed 
    from tblResults 
    where TotalMarks < 35
    group by SubjectId
    having count(SubjectId) > 20;
```